# php configuration: PHP executable not found

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I am trying to setup php in VSCode. I don't want it in my global settings, so in the workspace settings I have:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "php.validate.enable": true,
        "php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\php\\php.exe",
        "php.validate.run": "onType"
    }
}
```

I downloaded PHP to c:\php...

[image]

But am still getting this error when I fire up the workspce:

```
PHP executable not found. Install PHP 7 and add it to your PATH or set the php.executablePath setting
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You also need  to set `php.executablePath` inside the settings.json, so that everything works as it should.

To find the settings.json file go to;

> File -> Preferences -> User Settings -> Settings.json

And in this, make sure the following are set;

```
"php.executablePath": "C:\\php\\php.exe",
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\php\\php.exe"
```

Comment: This seems more of a comment than an answer?

Comment: But it fixed it as I thought. So it is the answer? Or what of the question answer part am I getting wrong? @Sam

Comment: @LukeFilewalker the trouble with something like this, it's a grey area, while it is "the answer" the answer does not constitute being an answer as it's too small (could bulk out with a manual and helpful comments to say why you need  to do this rather than "do this"?) it would work better as a comment

Comment: Ok, I think I got your point. I'll try to do some investigation and extend my answer so it better describes, why, this addtional setting is needed. Then it would fit?

Comment: @LukeFilewalker - it's not that it doesn't fit as it is now, and to be honest, if I were you, I wouldn't waste the time trying to find MSDN docs even if my life depended on it, I think it could be useful adding example locations of the file mentioned? Maybe adding an example of the relevant data/code in there?

Comment: Ok I'll try to improve it a bit later. Its quite hard getting it  better from a smartphone...

Comment: Thanks @SamSwift for styling my answer!